# XNA texture GetData exception

Tags: xna-4.0, textures, exceptions

When using this code:

```
public static Texture2D MakeTexRed(Texture2D tex)
    {
        Texture2D drawTex = new Texture2D(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice, tex.Width, tex.Height);
        Color[] data = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height];
        tex.GetData<Color>(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i].R = (byte)((data[i].R + 255) / 2);
            data[i].G /= 2;
            data[i].B /= 2;
        }
        drawTex.SetData(data);

        return drawTex;
    }
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
The type you are using for T in this method is an invalid size for this resource.
```

The size of the texture I'm using is 64x64 pixel.

When using this line:

```
Texture2D drawTex = new Texture2D(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice, tex.Width, tex.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
```

it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried specifying SurfaceFormat.Color in the Texture2D constructor?

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Sure you're not referencing the `Color` type from a different namespace? It's the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` namespace?

Comment: Yes, replacing Color with Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color also didn't help.

Comment: Is it throwing the exception in GetData or SetData? Also, the result of dividing a byte by an int is an int, so that could be causing your issue within the Color struct itself. Try changing data[i].G /= 2 to data[i].G = (byte)(data[i].G / 2), and the same for the blue component.

Comment: You're calling `GetData()` on the texture being passed in, not the one you're creating.  How is the texture being passed in constructed?  Where does it come from?

Comment: Try changing Color[] data = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height]; to Color[] data = new Color[(tex.Width * tex.Height) / 2];

Comment: Also check and see what tex.Format returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.surfaceformat.aspx) are the possible format types.

you are going to have to check tex.Format and use the correct datastructure for tex's SurfaceFormat.

For example.

```
var b = new Bgr565[result.Width * result.Height];
tex.SetData(b);
```

The below SurfaceFormat have a corresponding value types that can be used.

```
Color
Bgr565
Bgra5551
Bgra4444
NormalizedByte2
NormalizedByte4
Rgba1010102
Rg32
Rgba64
Alpha8
Single
Vector2
Vector4
HalfSingle
HalfVector2
HalfVector4
```

For the Dxt formats means that the texture is compressed you are going to need to know the size after the texture is compressed get the data and then decompress it.

After some searching I found a DXT1 and DXT5 [decompression library](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/2009/devblogs/s3tc-dxt1dxt5-texture-decompression/). Unfortunately I can't find anything managed so unsafe C# code is probably the best bet for converting it over. According to Wikipedia 16 pixels are stored in 8 bytes which makes have a byte per pixel so theoretically `byte[] data = new byte[(Width * Height) / 2]` should work for extracting the data.

```
Dxt1
Dxt3
Dxt5
```

This one is a special case just use HalfVector4 for the type and you are fine.

```
HdrBlendable
```

Comment: The format of the texture is Dxt1, how can I decompress it?

Comment: From my understanding of Dxt1 you can use 'byte[] data = new byte[(Width * Height) / 2]' to extract the data. Then you need to convert the linked to unmanaged c++ library to C#. I edited more info into the answer.

Comment: You might be able to draw the texture to a RenderTarget2D of the same size who has its SurfaceFormat set to Color and then unload the Dxt texture and replace it with the Color texture.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried not specifying the T when calling GetData() ?

```
tex.GetData<Color>(data);
```

To :

```
tex.GetData(data);
```

The error you posted refers to the Color you pass as T.

Comment: He's doing Color[] data = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height] so both lines of code will have exactly the same behavior.